# What is this calligraphic font?

Tags: fonts, typefaces, calligraphy

Does anyone know what this font is called? I have tried the font identifier programs online, but it wouldn't work because of all the swishes. I really love this font!!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not hand-lettered? The two 'e's and the two 'n's are very different to each other.

Comment: I don't think this is a font - it appears to be hand written - the letters N and E show variations you would not usually get with a font.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a font - or it has an enormous collection of variations - pairs as ligatures. Both e's are different, both n's are different. The beginnings and the endings have nothing common in some easily defineable way.

It can be manually drawn or modified from a font. I believe in the latter. Both cases need skill well above beginner's level and some talent, too.

One candidate for the starting font is Mallicot Script:

[image]

It's sold at least by FontSpring. Check their website. It can recommend nearly similar others.

Mallicot Script Extras is another font, but it's included, if one purchases Mallicot Script Regular. I believe those curly swishes are partly taken from the extras.